# How do we get to know to which response user has reacted(like/dislike) on MS teams?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We need help in understanding how Microsoft teams like and dislike works with BotFramework. When user clicks on like option provided in background we are getting reactionID but how do we get to know for which specific message user has given his feedback. Do we have this feasibility on Teams?

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the `replyToId`. Example from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-notifications#reactions):

> The `messageReaction` event is sent when a user adds or removes his or her reaction to a message which was originally sent by your bot. `replyToId` contains the ID of the specific message.

```
{
    "reactionsAdded": [
        {
            "type": "like"
        }
    ],
    "type": "messageReaction",
    "timestamp": "2017-10-16T18:45:41.943Z",
    "id": "f:9f78d1f3",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:1I9Is_Sx0O-Iy2rQ7Xz1lcaPKlO9eqmBRTBuW6XzkFtcjqxTjPaCMij8BVMdBcL9L_RwWNJyAHFQb0TRzXgyQvA",
        "aadObjectId": "c33aafc4-646d-4543-9d4c-abd28e4d2110"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "isGroup": true,
        "id": "19:3629591d4b774aa08cb0887902eee7c1@thread.skype"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:f5d48856-5b42-41a0-8c3a-c5f944b679b0",
        "name": "SongsuggesterLocal"
    },
    "channelData": {
        "channel": {
            "id": "19:3629591d4b774aa08cb0887902eee7c1@thread.skype"
        },
        "team": {
            "id": "19:efa9296d959346209fea44151c742e73@thread.skype"
        },
        "tenant": {
            "id": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47"
        }
    },
    "replyToId": "1:19uJ8TZA1cZcms7-2HLOW3pWRF4nSWEoVnRqc0DPa_kY"
}
```

Note, however, that this `replyToId` is specific to Teams and I don't believe it will persist if you set it yourself. Once you have that, you can [update the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165282/updating-an-activity-in-botframework-v4-on-teams-platform/55174866#55174866).

If you're trying to analyze which messages are reacted to, you might want to log the outgoing activity's `Id` and `Text` in [`TurnContext.OnSendActivities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.turncontext.onsendactivities?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_TurnContext_OnSendActivities_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_SendActivitiesHandler_). Then, when a reaction comes in, you can use the new [`Activity Handler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.activityhandler?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) to handle the message and add the reaction to your log. I believe this would come in [`OnUnrecognizedActivityTypeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.activityhandler.onunrecognizedactivitytypeasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_ActivityHandler_OnUnrecognizedActivityTypeAsync_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_ITurnContext_System_Threading_CancellationToken_). This is similar to the previous link, [update the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165282/updating-an-activity-in-botframework-v4-on-teams-platform/55174866#55174866).

Comment: Thanks @mdrichardson, Can we do it using Bot framework V3 as our current project is running on V3 and we are planning for migrating to V4.

Comment: [replyToId also exists in V3](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/blob/99fa2d1dcd3e838853d3704e587fb9a02f8ec7b8/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/ActivityEx.cs#L65), so you should be able to. You can also still [intercept and log messages](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/CSharp/core-Middleware)