# Sending proactive messages to MS Teams

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm not been able to send proactive messages to MS Teams.
You can see the code and errors belows.
The error messages are as below:
**Incorrect conversation creation parameters**

When i've put an application log in azure portal where the bot is hosted:
I'm seeing the following errors:
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter:
Exception caught : One or more errors occurred. (Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest')

> 2019-09-16T13:32:57
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException:
>   The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)--- End of inner exception stack trace ---at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmented(String prefix, Boolean useFlatBlobListing, BlobListingDetails blobListingDetails, Nullable`1 maxResults, BlobContinuationToken currentToken, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.CleanupOldBlobLogs(Object state)Request InformationRequestID:a8f8929d-001e-0005-4693-6ccae9000000RequestDate:Mon, 16 Sep 2019 13:32:57 GMTStatusMessage:The type of a blob in the container is unrecognized by this version.ErrorCode:FeatureVersionMismatch.
>   Could you please help me?
>   Thank you

```
 MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl);
            var teamConversationData = turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>();
            var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), _credentialProvider.AppId, _credentialProvider.Password);

            var userId = "28:2c988176-cea6-4aaa-9a69-8ace544a43e3";
            var tenantId = teamConversationData.Tenant.Id;
            var parameters = new ConversationParameters
            {
                Members = new[] { new ChannelAccount(userId) },
                ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
                {
                    Tenant = new TenantInfo(tenantId),
                },
            };

            var conversationResource = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(parameters);
            var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            message.Text = "This is a proactive message1.";
            await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(conversationResource.Id, (Activity)message);

            // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-create

V4 bot framework support in teams is beta (last I heard).  I wouldn't be surprised if proactive messages are buggy.  The version mismatch error may be due to teams expecting V3 payload.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned this in my email, but am re-posting here for others:

That’s because you’re not using a Teams UserId. They’re formatted like:

```
29:1I9Is_Sx0O-Iy2rQ7Xz1lcaPKlO9eqmBRTBuW6XzXXXXXXXXMij8BVMdBcL9L_RwWNJyAHFQb0TXXXXXX
```

I have a bunch of examples of the Teams formatting in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926125/10860086).

The easiest way to get all the info is to start a message with a user and set a breakpoint to grab an incoming message.

Alternatively, you can [query the roster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57499608/10860086).