# How to update an existing activity in WebChat

Tags: botframework

My scenario is: I send card attachments each with an AcceptButton to users. When 1 user clicks on that button, ideally I want to disable all similar buttons (of the same offer) for all users. I am storing conversation details of each user, and I know the ActivityId of each message-with-said-button (it follows a certain string format).

My issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532375/how-to-update-an-adaptive-card-which-is-already-sent-to-user-from-bot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165282/updating-an-activity-in-botframework-v4-on-teams-platform) but for WebChat not Teams.

I did try those solutions but I got the error "Method not allowed" for both UpdateActivityAsync() and DeleteActivityAsync(). Then I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57362223/8549603) that UpdateActivity is not supported in WebChat. [(But might be available in the future?)](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1384)

I would like any visual indication that the offer is no longer available. (Right now, they receive an "Offer was already accepted by {UserX}" which would still be in place on top of changing the card/message.)

Is there a way to do this via backChannel? I can trigger an event and pass the ActivityId (tested by showing a simple alert()) but how do I apply changes to that specific activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/ac5b6be8601207b05e2196fc3b0b2f07698961b0/packages/core/src/reducers/activities.js#L99) in Web Chat's source code and this open [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1384) in the Web Chat repository for adding support for `deleteActivity` and `updateActivity`, Update Activity events are not currently supported in Web Chat. Unfortunately, there is currently no way to really update an activity in Web Chat.

Hope this helps!