# How to Add a scroll bar to an adaptive card

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I m showing a list of users in a card, can I add a scrollbar to the card so that it fits the screen size?
I am currently using Adaptive card 1.0 and sending this card to MS Teams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AdaptiveCards do not allow scrolling or paging.

If you want to implement paging you could add a "next page" button to your card, when pressed you just update the card with the new list data.

MS Teams allows you to update cards/message you already sent so you could send the first page and when a user clicks on the action button you sent the second page etc.

Answer (score 1):

AdaptiveCards do not have the ability to specify scrolling.But we can do with Carousel feature.

```
{
   attachmentLayout: Attacenter code herehmentLayoutTypes.Carousel,
   attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard()]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[AdaptiveCards do not have the ability to specify scrolling](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/). It would be up to the client to implement this functionality. However, you may be able to send a [list card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#list-card), depending on if it suits your needs.

Comment: is there any alternative as in if we can have pagination if not scroll bar

Comment: @Anu I was afraid you were using BotFramework. Unfortunately, List Cards are not currently supported. Tim's answer is really the only workaround. [Here's how to update cards in Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165282/updating-an-activity-in-botframework-v4-on-teams-platform/55174866#55174866)

Comment: Thanks @mdrichardson-MSFT :)