# Why doesn't the Azure Bot Service Slack connector forward Events and Interactive Messages?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, slack

**Update: June 30, 2020**

After more testing, I have details that might help someone recognize my problem.

The issue seems to be that Slack is sending data to Azure Bot Services, but that data isn't being forwarded to my code.  Ive been able to use the Bot Emulator without any problems and the Azure Web Chat works fine.

I know that the Slack configuration for the OAuth Redirect URL is correct (I was able to add my bot to Slack) and the Request URL for Events is correct (they sent the 'challenge' and it's verified).  I've subscribed to the exact Scopes and Events that are in the Microsoft documentation and I've verified that the Interactivity and Events options are enabled.

When a user types text in my bot's Slack channel, my app receives "message" activity and my code can send a response, so it looks like Microsoft can communicate end-to-end for normal messages.  I do not receive any data when users first join my bot (like a ConversationUpdate) or if they click a button in a dialog.  I can see Slack sending data when a button is pressed, it just never arrives.

As a test, I copied the Messaging Endpoint from my Azure bot settings and pasted it into Slack's Interactivity "Request URL" and when I click a button in Slack I can see the data that Slack is sending (sadly in a format that my code can't handle).

**Original Post**

I have a Bot Framework app (v4) that I've written in nodejs.  It works well and I have an ActivityHandler that responds to people being added to a conversation and when they send messages.  I was able to get pro-active messaging functioning and everything was great until I tried to get interactivity working.

I started off using some sample button code from Microsoft's documentation:

```
let reply = MessageFactory.suggestedActions(['Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue'], 'What is the best color?');
await turnContext.sendActivity(reply);
```

This works fine in the emulator, but in Slack it renders as a bulleted list. It looks like that's the way that "suggested actions" [are handled in Slack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

I changed my code to use a "hero card":

```
let card = CardFactory.heroCard(
    'What is the best color?',
    undefined,
    CardFactory.actions([
        {
            type: 'imBack',
            title: 'Color Red',
            value: 'Red Value'
        }
    ])
);
let reply = MessageFactory.attachment(card);
await turnContext.sendActivity(reply);
```

This works okay in the emulator, except my app thinks the user typed "Red Value" and the button stays on-screen and is still clickable.  I might be able to work around that, but the button doesn't work at all in Slack.  It is rendered fine, but I don't get a notification in my app.

Clicking the button shows an HTTP request to:

```
https://{MY_SLACK}.slack.com/api/chat.attachmentAction?_x_id=f8d003c3-1592436018.632&_x_csid=NcWi3y50lFU&slack_route={OTHER_SLACK_STUFF}
```

And I can see that the request POSTs all sorts of data including:

```
payload: {"actions":[{"id":"1","name":"imBack","text":"Color Red","type":"button","value":"Red Value","style":"default"}],"attachment_id":"2","callback_id":"{MAGIC_NUMBER}:{TEAM_ID}","channel_id":"{CHANNEL_ID}","message_ts":"1592435983.056000","prompt_app_install":false,"team_id":"{TEAM_ID}"}
```

I'm not sure how to see anything useful in the Azure Portal - the analytics option for my bot doesn't seem to work and the activities option only says "Write a Bot Service".  I don't see any sign of the message going from Slack to Azure.

I'm developing locally and configured ngrok so that my messaging endpoint in Azure could be set to https://69fe1382ce17.ngrok.io/api/messages On the Slack side of things, I've configured the Interactivity Request URL to be https://slack.botframework.com/api/Actions  The Event Subscription Request URL is [https://slack.botframework.com/api/Events/{MY_BOT_NAME}](https://slack.botframework.com/api/Events/%7BMY_BOT_NAME%7D)

What I would like is a set of buttons with different options and when the user clicks one, my bot gets some sort of "value" instead of message text.  I'd also like for the button to go away so the user can't send repeated commands.  It would be nice if the hero card collapsed with just the prompt being displayed.

Are there any interactive options that work for Slack and other channels?

Thanks!

- Lee

Comment: I understand that you are still not satisfied because interactive messages are not working for you. But are you satisfied with my answer when it comes to the other parts of your question? [A fix for Slack is on the way.](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/4246#issuecomment-655444461)

Answer (score 1):

I know linking to another site with no additional detail is frowned upon, but I don't have enough expertise to answer your question. I suspect the link here might move you in the right direction:
[Choice Prompts are not translated over to Slack format #3974](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/3974)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that issue - there was info there that verified how I was supposed to be formatting the options.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is multifaceted so I'll try to break it down into smaller pieces.

### What's the deal with suggested actions in Slack?

Suggested actions are not supported in Slack, but the Bot Builder SDK thinks they are. This is a longstanding bug. I've just reported it again on the docs page you linked: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1742

This means you would encounter problems if you were trying to have the choice factory automatically generate the right kind of choices for your channel. You're not doing that, so you should be fine. Hero cards are supposed to work in Slack.

### Why aren't hero cards working in Slack?

First I need to mention that hero cards only work with the Slack connector and not the Slack adapter. You seem to be using the connector so you should be fine.

I suspect your problem is related to how you've configured your bot's settings on the Slack side. There is a step in the [Bot Framework doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=abs#add-and-configure-interactive-messages-optional) that seems to be important if you want to get buttons to work. If you've followed the doc exactly and you still can't get buttons to work, it may be worthwhile to dig into the [Slack API documentation](https://api.slack.com/interactivity).

### How do I only allow a button to be clicked once?

You can [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference#update-activity) or [delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference#delete-activity) the activity. There's no easy way to do this, but if you voice your support for my [cards library](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/issues/137) then it can be done for you automatically.

The Slack connector actually puts a lot of relevant information in the incoming activity's channel data, and you can use that to figure out what activity the incoming activity came from. That would take some experimentation on your part.

There's another approach that works on more channels than just Slack. It's real complicated, but if you wanna tackle this then here are the basic steps:

1. You need to put an ID in the action data to help your bot identify the action.
2. You need to save the activity ID that gets returned when you send the action to Slack.
3. You need to associate the returned activity ID with the ID you put in the action data.
4. You need to retrieve the activity ID using the action data ID when the user clicks the button.
5. You need to use that activity ID to update or delete the activity.

Unfortunately there's no centralized guide to help you do this, but there are many examples explaining it scattered across Stack Overflow. Here is a good one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174866/2122672

Comment: To test the Slack settings, I changed the "Interactivity Request URL" from https://slack.botframework.com/api/Actions to https://69fe7182ce17.ngrok.io/api/messages  Clicking the button, my code gets the POST data that is supposed to be handled by the Bot Framework: `payload={"type"%3A"interactive_message"%2C"actions"%3A ... }`

I've never seen an Event or Button Action being sent from Slack to my code.  Are those two supposed to go from Slack to botframework.com and then to my bot's endpoint?

Can I use the Azure Portal to see what actions Slack is sending botframework.com?

Comment: Yes, the Azure Bot Service Slack connector is supposed to forward the messages to your bot using the Bot Framework protocol. If you have an app insights resource hooked up to your bot then you can check the logs blade, the search blade, etc. It's possible that that particular issue can't be resolved here on Stack Overflow and you'll have to make a support request through Azure, but I hope you'll accept my answer anyway because I answered your multiple questions as fully as I could. Anyway... it's not likely to be relevant, but which Slack clients have you tried?