# Microsoft Bot Framework respond to Slack Block Kit UI Action Buttons

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

Using Microsoft Bot Framework Composer, I am sending a Slack Block Kit UI message that contains action buttons. Slack correctly displays the message, but pressing any of the action buttons results in a 400 error.

[image: Slack Message]

I have enabled Interactivity and set the Request URL to https://slack.botframework.com/api/Actions

[image: Slack Interactivity Request URL]

Is this correct? I've tried updating to https://04458ba4816c.ngrok.io/api/slack, but then get 401 not authorized.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

[Why doesn't the Azure Bot Service Slack connector forward Events and Interactive Messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62440845/why-doesnt-the-azure-bot-service-slack-connector-forward-events-and-interactive)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: No, sorry I didn't find a solution.